# Как удалить в файле строку которую выберет человек?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл my_name.txt . Он содержит несколько записей имен. Хочу написать программу которая удаляет запись с именем студента которого я напишет человек.
Я написал код но он не удаляет имени с файла. Если что я только учусь
Пример в текстовом файле my_name:
Максим
Вова
Игорь

```
def main():

    a = input('Кого удалить?: ')
    infile = open('my_name.txt', 'r')
    descr = infile.readline()
    while descr != '':
        descr = descr.rstrip('\n')
        if descr == a:
            infile.rstrip(a)
            print('Файл удален')
        descr = infile.readline()

    infile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Сбросте пример my_name.txt

Comment: в вашем коде нету записи в файл

Comment: Пример в текстовом файле my_name: Максим\n Вова\n Игорь\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будет работать при условии, что каждое имя записано с новой строки.

```py
removeName = input('name: ')
namesList  = []

with open('file.txt') as f:     # открыть файл для чтения
    textList = f.readlines()    # прочитать по строкам

for i in textList:
    namesList.append(i.replace('\n','')) # убрать переводы строк из списка

if removeName in namesList:
    num = namesList.index(removeName)   # найти положение удаляемого имени
    namesList.pop(num)                  # удалить имя из списка

    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:    # открыть файл для записи ('w')
        namesText = ''
        for i in namesList:
            namesText += i + '\n'       # добавить переводы строк
        f.write(namesText)              # переписать файл
else:
    print('there is no such name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
fileName = 'my_name.txt'
a = input('Кого удалить?: ')

with open(fileName, "r") as infile:
    descr = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')
    _lines= []
    while descr:
        if descr != a:
            _lines.append(descr)
        descr = infile.readline().rstrip('\n')

with open(fileName, "w") as outfile: 
    print(*[ line for line in _lines ], sep="\n", file=outfile)
```